# Postgres optimization failing to filter window function partitions early

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-performance

In some cases, PostgreSQL does not filter out window function partitions until they are calculated, while in a very similar scenario PostgreSQL filters row before performing window function calculation.

Tables used for minimal STR - `log` is the main data table, each row contains either `increment` or `absolute` value. Absolute value resets the current `counter` with a new base value. Window functions need to process all logs for a given `account_id` to calculate the correct running total. View uses a subquery to ensure that underlying `log` rows are not filtered by `ts`, otherwise, this would break the window function.

```
CREATE TABLE account(
  id serial,
  name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE log(
  id serial,
  absolute int,
  incremental int,
  account_id int,
  ts timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_account
      FOREIGN KEY(account_id)
    REFERENCES account(id)

);

CREATE FUNCTION get_running_total_func(
    aggregated_total int,
    absolute int,
    incremental int
) RETURNS int
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT AS
$$
   SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN absolute IS NOT NULL THEN absolute 
            ELSE COALESCE(aggregated_total, 0) + incremental
        END
$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE get_running_total(integer, integer) (
   sfunc = get_running_total_func,
   stype = integer
);
```

Slow view:

```
 CREATE VIEW test_view
 (
   log_id,
   running_value,
   account_id,
   ts
 )
 AS
     SELECT log_running.* FROM
 (SELECT
   log.id,
     get_running_total(
       log.absolute,
       log.incremental
   )
   OVER(
       PARTITION BY log.account_id
       ORDER BY log.ts RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
   ),
   account.id,
   ts
   FROM log log JOIN account account ON log.account_id=account.id
  ) AS log_running;
CREATE VIEW
postgres=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test_view WHERE account_id=1;
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on log_running  (cost=12734.02..15981.48 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=7510.851..16122.404 rows=20 loops=1)
   Filter: (log_running.id_1 = 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 99902
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=12734.02..14732.46 rows=99922 width=32) (actual time=7510.830..14438.783 rows=99922 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=12734.02..12983.82 rows=99922 width=28) (actual time=7510.628..9312.399 rows=99922 loops=1)
               Sort Key: log.account_id, log.ts
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3328kB
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=143.50..2042.24 rows=99922 width=28) (actual time=169.941..5431.650 rows=99922 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (log.account_id = account.id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on log  (cost=0.00..1636.22 rows=99922 width=24) (actual time=0.063..1697.802 rows=99922 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=81.00..81.00 rows=5000 width=4) (actual time=169.837..169.865 rows=5000 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 240kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on account  (cost=0.00..81.00 rows=5000 width=4) (actual time=0.017..84.639 rows=5000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.199 ms
 Execution Time: 16127.275 ms
(15 rows)
```

Fast view - only change is `account.id` -> `log.account_id` (!):

```
 CREATE VIEW test_view
 (
  log_id,
  running_value,
  account_id,
  ts
 )
 AS
     SELECT log_running.* FROM
 (SELECT
   log.id,
     get_running_total(
       log.absolute,
       log.incremental
   )
   OVER(
       PARTITION BY log.account_id
       ORDER BY log.ts RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
   ),
   log.account_id,
   ts
   FROM log log JOIN account account ON log.account_id=account.id
   ) AS log_running;
CREATE VIEW
postgres=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test_view WHERE account_id=1;
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on log_running  (cost=1894.96..1895.56 rows=20 width=20) (actual time=34.718..45.958 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1894.96..1895.36 rows=20 width=28) (actual time=34.691..45.307 rows=20 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=1894.96..1895.01 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=34.367..35.925 rows=20 loops=1)
               Sort Key: log.ts
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..1894.53 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=0.542..34.066 rows=20 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Only Scan using account_pkey on account  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.025..0.054 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (id = 1)
                           Heap Fetches: 1
                     ->  Seq Scan on log  (cost=0.00..1886.03 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=0.195..32.937 rows=20 loops=1)
                           Filter: (account_id = 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 99902
 Planning Time: 0.297 ms
 Execution Time: 47.300 ms
(14 rows)
```

Is it a bug in PostgreSQL implementation? It seems that this change in view definition shouldn't affect performance at all, PostgreSQL should be able to filter data before applying window function for all data set.

Comment: First I would create an index on log.account_id and log.ts before anything else. Do you see any difference in the query plan when these indexes are available?

Comment: I've added index and re-run queries, index doesn't change anything.
As far as I understand the issue is not with sequential scan on `log`, but with the absence of `filter` before `WindowAgg`.

Comment: Rows Removed by Filter: 99902 still happens, even with an index on account_id ?

Comment: Are you sure about this part of the function: COALESCE(total, 0) IS NOT NULL Because of COALESCE, this will always be TRUE, whatever the value of total is.

Comment: Output with index is identical to "Slow view" output, only numbers change a little bit, without any major changes.
I've fixed the part with `COALESCE`, thanks! However, this does not change timings.

Comment: test_view.account_id is different in both examples, in the slow query it is account.id and in the fast one log.account_id. That changes your WHERE condition, because that's done on the VIEW and it looks like you already have issues with indexes and/or constraints. Could you execute the plain query, just the subquery and not the view or the outer query? And put the result from explain analyse over here?

Comment: Sure, here are results without a view: slow with a subquery, fast with a subquery, and two examples without subquery - both of them are executed fast: https://gist.github.com/K0Te/d74c4edb76ee9e059682d25718c31816

Comment: And what happens when you create a view, without using a subquery? Because it looks like that using a subquery results in a bad query plan.

Comment: It also performs slowly: https://gist.github.com/K0Te/dfa35690bc6972865f4b6b7df5b83eb7 , which is very surprising for me.
The subquery is part of a design - I want the client (reporting system) not to be able to break window function calculation. Without subqueury client could filter by `ts` and this would affect window function results for a given `log.id`.

Comment: Put your code into a function and use input parameters to limit the fields that your customer can use. Just like an API